# Deploy a springboot 2.1.4 in weblogic 12.1.3 error

Tags: spring-boot, weblogic

I develop a spring boot app (version 2.1.4) but when i tried to deploy on weblogic 12.1.3 i have this error:

[image]

I deployed it on a wildfly 17 and it works.

¿any idea who i can solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the server log?

Answer (score 0):

Latest WebLogic 12c only supports Spring 4 (4.2 I think).
Springboot 2.x requires Spring 5
Since WebLogic 12c does not support Spring 5, it does not support Springboot 2.x
But if you figure something out, do let me know :)